# Where does the object created by this Swift function go?

Tags: swift, github

I am looking at this branch on GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/westerlund/eae8ec71cdac88be7c3a

This is the function, used to create a GIF from UIImages in Swift:

```
    func createGIF(with images: [UIImage], loopCount: Int = 0, frameDelay: Double, callback: (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> ()) { 
     let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: loopCount]] 
     let frameProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: frameDelay]] 

     let documentsDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory() 
     let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("animated.gif") 

     if let url = url { 
        let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeGIF, UInt(images.count), nil) 
         CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties) 

         for i in 0..<images.count { 
             CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, images[i].CGImage, frameProperties) 
         } 

         if CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) { 
             callback(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: url), error: nil) 
         } else { 
             callback(data: nil, error: NSError()) 
         } 
     } else  { 
         callback(data: nil, error: NSError()) 
     } 
 }
```

I am not sure I understand what is going on. Shouldn't the function return an object to be used? Where does the created GIF go? Is it possible to use it in other parts of my code, for instance to put it in a UIImageView, or UIImage?

Thank you

Comment: into the callback? This line `callback(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: url), error: nil)`

Comment: So from there I should use the NSData to create a UIImage then?

Comment: Sounds about right, mind the cases when data is nil and error is not.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result GIF is passed as `NSData` into the `callback` then you can create your `NSImage` from it. Note that the same callback is used in error conditions - then `data` is `nil` and `error` is not.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I can't figure out how to create a UIImage from NSData. All functions related to UIImage and data use a type "Data", that is apparently not equivalent to NSData, as I get a type error when I try to use the data created by the callback...

Comment: There's a ctor that takes NSData (switch to Swift on the page): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithData: